# How many rays can one RT core calculate simultaneously?

Tags: raytracing, gpu

I have noticed that all GeForce RTX cards, without exception, have an equal number of RT cores as they have streaming multiprocessors (SM). From this fact I assume that each RT core is associated with one SM. In other words, each SM has an RT core available for it to use.

But I am curious to know: How many rays can one RT core calculate simultaneously? Is it just one, or is it more than one?

Given that an SM has (typically) 128 cores, I wouldn't be surprised if an RT core can likewise calculate 128 rays simultaneously, so that each SM core can have its own ray. Maybe even a multiple of 128, so that each SM core can have several rays traced at once. However, I cannot find corroboration of this anywhere.